# Drop down option code not working?

Tags: php

My site works until I put this code in:

```
    <option id="" name="" value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>" selected>1</option>
```

once I put that in, the site goes blank.  It's part of a while loop in a drop down menu.

supposed to look like this:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

    print '<option id="" name="" value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>" selected>1</option>'; 
        }
```

Comment: An option with name and id? Is it even surrounded by select tags?

Comment: *"Not working"*, isn't much for us to go on. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php <(page goes blank)
and apply that to your code and view your HTML source.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt - yes, the select tag is outside of the loop.  And yes, I do have error reporting but no error messages were shown, which is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put `<?php` `?>` tag inside php code. Try like this -

```
print '<option id="" name="" value="'.$row['Name'] .'" selected>'.$row['Name'] .'</option>';
```

Comment: that code worked, but how would you do it if I put echo instead of print?

Comment: Same. Just replace print with echo.

Comment: Site crashed again.  and how would I put $row['Name'] in between selected> and </option>?

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

    echo '<option id="" name="name" value="'.$row['name'].'">1</option>'; 
        }
```

Note that you are adding `selected` in while loop so it will print selected to every option,you should add condition to add selected value..